# jQuery - Transfer class to another element if the class has specific word in it?

Tags: jquery, html, dom-manipulation

I have this problem that i want to *transfer* specific ( yet not that specific ) classes from element to another.

this:

```
<span>
   <span class="THIS-something-something anotherClass"></span>
</span>
```

into:

```
<span class="THIS-something-something">
   <span class="anotherClass"></span>
</span>
```

**Basic idea is that if you write a class in that inner span that has specific word "THIS" it would get transfered to the outer span** ( the outer span is generated there with .wrap )

class with "THIS" is a class that has like.. 20 different variations ( THIS-something-something, THIS-something-anything, THIS-and-that ..and so on.. ) and "anotherClass" is totally random class and there would possibly be multiple of those as well..depending on how many i would like to insert.

I have no idea how that would go down.. Am i maybe thinking about this all wrong?

I can only make it so that all classes get copied to the outer span and then i would remove all classes from the inner span.. but that kinda defeats all purposes as it doesnt leave "anotherClass" and it copies that to the outer element...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('span > span').each(function() {
    var all = $(this).attr('class').split(' ');
    for (var i = 0; i < all.length; ++i) {
        var cls = all[i];
        if (cls.indexOf('THIS-') == 0) {
            $(this).parent().addClass(cls);
            $(this).removeClass(cls);
        }
    }
});
```

This *may* have problems relating to order of processing, hence why the selector requires a span inside another span.

Comment: There was a typo (a instead of all).  I've fixed it now: http://jsfiddle.net/alnitak/Gwvpx/

Comment: It still seems to do nothing.

Comment: I didn't update the fiddle properly (the code above was OK, though).  It's fine now.

Comment: Alright, it seems to be doing it now.. im gonna try if i can get it to work in my code. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
$('span[class|="THIS"]').removeClass(function (index, class) {
    var thisclass=class.match(/THIS-[^\s]+/g).join(' ');
    $(this).parent().addClass(thisclass);
    return thisclass;
});
```

<del>I can't test it right now, but later I will post a jsFiddle. The regex should be worked on, I just wanted to give you an outline.</del>

The baseline is the usage of [`.removeClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/) with a function and the [Attribute Contains Prefix Selector [name|="value"]](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-prefix-selector/).

**UPDATE:** fixed the code and added [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/my5ZL/2/). The code grabs all the classnames starting with `THIS-` on `span`s and moves them to their parent (you can run it after `wrap()` or get rid of my selector and use yours like `$(myselector).wrap(mystuff).removeClass(...);`).